# Why I can't installing go library

Tags: go

I try to install `github.com/lib/pq` with `go get github.com/lib/pq`. When I import this in my go file, I got this error:

```
cannot load github.com/lib/pq: open /Applications/performance enginnering/go-getting-started/vendor/github.com/lib/pq: no such file or directory
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `-mod=vendor` flag when building? DId you initially downloaded this module to vendor directory?

Comment: I am new to go. Could you elaborate more on the steps that I should check and do?

Comment: Do you have vendor directory in root of your project?

Comment: yes, I have vendor directory.

Comment: Try to run `go mod vendor` -- it will place all your dependencies in `vendor` directory and then build project again.

Comment: Once I delete vendor folder, the import works. Not sure why. Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you tried to run `go mod vendor`? Yes, it works because if you have `vendor` directory in you project, go1.14 assumes that all you dependencies are stored there. But if you run `go get ...` it stores module in module cache

Comment: Which version of Go are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First you should use go modules if you are developing new go project rather than vendoring.

Try setting your GOPATH environment variable, After setting your GOPATH when you run go get command dependencies will be installed at $GOPATH/pkg directory. and you should place your code inside $GOPATH/src directory.